# How to protect source code from being copied or leaked by employes

Tags: project-management, code-security

I'm a Java Developer, I created a Desktop Application , that is Free, and now I'm about to finish the payed version. my question is when I create a startup and other developers work on my code. How can I prevent them from copying the source code and take it home or leak it?? and is there is a software for that, what there names are?? and I need the name of some kind of software that keep track of every activity the user make (keyboard keys pressed, website visited even if history is deleted, software installed ...). I will be using Windows. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you really think this is a thing that would actually happen?

Comment: what thing are you talking about ???

Comment: The thing you are worrying about. Employees stealing and publishing the source code.

Comment: then it cannot be done ??? how big companies do that, for example you will never find windows source code, not even a part of it

Comment: Most of the things you want to do is considered illegal, at least in the country where I live.

Comment: Windows source code has been leaked before. Everything has been leaked. It usually doesn't matter because there's far, far more to making money off of software than simply writing the source code.

Comment: http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/2/15/71552/7795 - there ain't much you can do unfortunately. Protect yourself (legally) with a contract, and tackle the reasons you think may motivate them to do this at the 'source'. i.e. encourage them toward wanting to work with you instead of rob you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're anticipating is a social problem; trying to create a technological solution to it is a bad idea.  All that does is put you in a technological arms race against the attacker--assuming anyone actually does try to do that, of course.

The way you keep your employees from doing harmful things to screw you over is to put in their contract that they can't do harmful things to screw you over.  Then, if they violate that, you have the law on your side, which is a lot more useful than having some technology (that a determined attacker is probably going to find a way to circumvent) on your side.